# Загрузка нескольких картинок в БД ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Так выглядит input:

```
<input type="file" name="uploadImage" min = "1" max = "9999" multiple = "true" />
```

Вот контроллер:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadImageTest(BLL.Model.ImageViewModelItem item)
{
    HttpPostedFileBase images = Request.Files["uploadImage"];
    BLL.Providers.ImageDbProvider imgDbProv = new BLL.Providers.ImageDbProvider();

    if (ModelState.IsValid && item != null)
    {
        byte[] imageData = null;
        using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(images.InputStream))
        {
            imageData = binaryReader.ReadBytes(images.ContentLength);
            item.ImageItem = imageData;
        }
    }

    imgDbProv.Add(item);

    return RedirectToAction("ImagesTest");

}
```

Когда я выбираю несколько картинок и отправляю их в input, передается только одна картинка (первая). Как передавать несколько картинок сразу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну вы и работаете с одним файлом. Пример для вдохновения:

```
private AttachmentData[] GetPostedAttachments()
{
    var attachments = new List<AttachmentData>();
    for (var i = 0; i < this.Request.Files.Count; i++)
    {
        var file = this.Request.Files[i];
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(file?.FileName))
            continue;

        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        using (var s = file.InputStream)
            s.CopyTo(ms);

        var attach = new AttachmentData
        {
            FileName = file.FileName,
            ContentType = file.ContentType,
            Content = ms.ToArray()
        };

        attachments.Add(attach);
    }

    return attachments.ToArray();
}
```

где:

```
public class AttachmentData
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }

    public string ContentType { get; set; }

    public byte[] Content { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за пример, я понял свои ошибки.