# Upload Images , Asp.Net core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

пытаюсь загрузить images в бд или на сервер , но не получается. может кто нибудь поможет мне

Models:

```
public class Phone 
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }
        public string ImageName { get; set; }
        public byte[] Image { get; set; } 
        public  List<Purchase> Purchases { get; set; }
    }
```

Views:

```
<form asp-action="AddFile" asp-controller="Crud" method="post" action=" ">
    <input type="file" name="uploadedFile" /><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Загрузить" />
</form>
```

controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> AddFile(IFormFile uploadedFile)
        {
            if (uploadedFile != null)
            {
                // путь к папке Files
                string path = "/Files/" + uploadedFile.FileName;
                // сохраняем файл в папку Files в каталоге wwwroot
                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(_phoneRepository.WebRootPath + path, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await uploadedFile.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                }
                Phone file = new Phone { ImageName = uploadedFile.FileName, Path = path };
                Db.Phones.Add(file);
                Db.SaveChanges();
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

WebRootPath выдаёт ошибку :

```
'IPhoneRepository' does not contain a definition for 'WebRootPath' and no accessible extension method 'WebRootPath' accepting a first argument of type 'IPhoneRepository' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS1061) [Shop]
```

FileMode.Create:

```
Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.IO.FileMode' to 'System.IO.FileAccess' (CS1503) [Shop]
```

Comment: в том же примере почему не взяли код контроллера? https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/21.3.php

Comment: там плохой пример

Comment: смотрите пример сохранения в базу данных

Comment: В вопросе нет инфы о том, что не получилось, в комментариях нет информации чем плох пример метанита. Приведите информацию что не так, чтобы можно было дать ответ на вопрос. В поиске по stackoverflow находится множество вопросов о загрузке файлов, чем они не походят? А то может закроем как дубликат на один из ранее данных ответов? Вот [загрузка одной картинки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/837690/213987), вот [нескольких за раз](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/694067/213987) - примеров масса, это я только из своих вспомнил.

Comment: я изменил код можете посмотреть

Comment: _phoneRepository - это что за объект?

Comment: [Getting the Web Root Path and the Content Root Path in ASP.NET Core](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/getting-the-web-root-path-and-the-content-root-path-in-asp-net-core)